# Why do I see a "force promotion" button when using the Jenkins Promoted Builds plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When using the Jenkins Promoted Builds plugin, why do I see a "Force promotion" option? It sometimes appears either instead of or in addition to the expected "Approve" button.

Answer (score 1):

The "Force Promotion" button seems to appear when you are not an "official" approver for a manual approval step or some other promotion condition has not yet been met - and you have the "Promotion" permission associated with your Jenkins role.

In addition, for at least some roles providers (like Cloudbees RBAC), the promotion plugin doesn't appear to recognize group names for manual approvers.  For this case you will have to put in the full email address of the approvers - then they get the actual "approve" button.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Force Promotion</kbd> button appears when you have global or job-local credentials, in particular the **"Promote" credential**. Please note when you click <kbd>Force Promotion</kbd>, it then becomes <kbd>Re-Execute Promotion</kbd>. The functionality remains the same. It will not be shown if user is not logged in.

The <kbd>Approve</kbd> button is different, and appears only to *approved* promoters, as specified in the job configuration's **promotion configuration**. If no list of approvers is provided, it will be shown to everyone. It will be shown even if no user is logged in. It is worth noting that the "approve" action cannot be re-executed (unless with <kbd>Force Promotion</kbd>)

Comment: In my installation, the "Promote" button is actually called "Approve", fwiw.  Also, I don't believe global or job-local admin credentials are strictly required - at least in my setup (with RBAC), promotion is an explicit privilege you can grant to any role.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it's called 'approve', that was a typo. I've also made the part about credentials more clear. We are saying the same thing in that regard.